# getting jav.lang.illegalStateException: error

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So I was trying to make my first app but while running it, I get the following notification "jav.lang.illegalStateException: expected a boolean but was NUMBER at line 1 column 185 path $.recipes[0].weightWAtcherSmartPoints" and the app doesn't go beyond the loading screen

Comment: Looks like you're going to parse Json in the app. And some field that you are trying to parse like a boolean, actually it is a number.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.